# Covert application.conf to application.yaml

Tags: java, spring, yaml, micronaut

How do I can create a list in yaml file?

I have below application.conf file.

```
mappings = [
{
  partnerId = "partner1"
  stagePolicyMapping = [
    { stage = "Assignment Call",
      policy = "underwriting"
    },
    { stage = "Collect Docs",
      policy = "collectverify"
    },
    { stage = "Partial Application",
      policy = "partialapp"
    }
  ]
},
{
  partnerId = "partner2"
  stagePolicyMapping = [
    { stage = "Application Received",
      policy = "appreceivedusa"
    },
    { stage = "Application Incomplete",
      policy = "incompleteapp"
    },
    { stage = "Partial Application",
      policy = "partialapp"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to switch to application.yml file. Below is what I have so far. I am not sure how to create list of stage and policy properties.

```
# policy mappings
mappings:
  partnerId:
    partner1:
      stage: Assignment Call
      policy: underwriting

???? stage and policy again ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [**documentation**](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) of YAML, it starts with a [**preview**](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#Preview) which immediately shows example of a list (aka a *sequence*):

> **Example 2.4.  Sequence of Mappings
>
>   (players’ statistics)**
>
> ```
>   -
>     name: Mark McGwire
>     hr:   65
>     avg:  0.278
>   -
>     name: Sammy Sosa
>     hr:   63
>     avg:  0.288
> ```

So you data should be:

```
mappings:
  -
    partnerId: partner1
    stagePolicyMapping:
      -
        stage: Assignment Call
        policy: underwriting
      -
        stage: Collect Docs
        policy: collectverify
      -
        stage: Partial Application
        policy: partialapp
  -
    partnerId: partner2
    stagePolicyMapping:
      -
        stage: Application Received
        policy: appreceivedusa
      -
        stage: Application Incomplete
        policy: incompleteapp
      -
        stage: Partial Application
        policy: partialapp
```

You can also do it more compact as shown in [answer by michalk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56278970/5221149).

Comment: Thanks you for the quick response

Answer (score 2):

Something like :

```
mappings:
- partnerId: partner1
  stagePolicyMapping:
  - stage: Assignment Call
    policy: underwriting
  - stage: Collect Docs
    policy: collectverify
  - stage: Partial Application
    policy: partialapp
- partnerId: partner2
  stagePolicyMapping:
  - stage: Application Received
    policy: appreceivedusa
  - stage: Application Incomplete
    policy: incompleteapp
  - stage: Partial Application
    policy: partialapp
```